# What rights are required to automate DevEnv.exe to build a website

Tags: windows-server-2003, teamcity, build-agent

Environment: TeamCity 6.5.1 on Win2k3, BuildAgent(s) on Win2k3, Visual Studio 2k10, .NET v4, Nant 0.91

I'm completing the setup of TeamCity and am trying to lock down the BuildAgent account on the build machine(s) per our security guidelines. The build is crashing the first time "devenv.exe /build" is called via the Nant script:

> Faulting application devenv.exe, version 10.0.30319.1, stamp 4ba1fab3,
>   faulting module msenv.dll, version 10.0.30319.1, stamp 4ba1fd94,
>   debug? 0, fault address 0x0000c36b.

I had no luck googling that message. However, if I change the BuildAgent Service from the Local Network Account to the Administrator account, things work. However, if I use another domain account, it fails. Also fails if I add that domain account to the local Administrators group.

Any ideas on what I'm missing? Is there a specific privilege you need to have in order for a "DevEnv /build" to work without crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuck, I just went through this recently.  First, use `devenv.com`, not `devenv.exe`. The devenv with the com extension can build a solution and send all output to the console, without using the gui.  As the TeamCity agent is a service, it may not be allowed to interact with the gui at all.

Second, and I realize that this might not be possible for you (especially if you are building an MSI), but consider doing whatever you need to do to use the built in Visual Studio build runner that comes with TeamCity.  It does utilize MSBuild to do its work.  If you go this route and you *still* need devenv, then go find [MSBuild Extensions Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/), which has already solved a lot of these issues with their own devenv build task.

Honestly, I ended up replacing Microsoft's installation projects with alternatives (InstallShield or WiX), and never looked back.

Comment: I'll give it a try. I forgot to mention that TeamCity is calling Nant to do the builds. Right now we're before MSI creation, just trying to get the site built in debug mode for validation.

Comment: Taking your advice and recommending we move from Web Sites projects to Web Applications obviating our need for Devenv.com and moving to an easier build. Thanks!